# display error disabled, but still show errors!

Tags: magento-1.8, index

I disabled display error in index and deleted cache but still errors display and don't let me to continue my job!
How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: Maybe it will make sense to solve these errors? ;)

Answer (score 1):

You also need to make sure that the Magento::setIsDeveloperMode(true) to be inside the if condition like:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}
```

Usually, we do not need display error to be set to false, as this condition will do the same and if you put the statement outside of the if condition then it will show errors, no matter what.